# A matrices problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two real $n\times n$ matrices such that $AB=BA$,show that $|A^2+B^2|\ge 0$.

Comment: I can't think of a definition of $|\cdot|$ such that $|C|<0$ for some $C$...

Comment: @John Determinant....

Comment: Ah! My bad, too used to that norm notation. @N.S.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Since $AB=BA$ you have
$$A^2+B^2=(A+iB)(A-iB) \Rightarrow \det(A^2+B^2)=\det(A+iB) \det(A-iB)$$

Now, use $\det(A-iB)=\overline{\det(A+iB)}$.

Comment: Is $det(A + iB)$ always real?

Comment: Is $C =(A+iB)(A-iB)$ positive-definite?

Comment: @DanielCunha No, it is not. Pick $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0 &0 \end{bmatrix}, B= \begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$. As for the second question, $A^2$ is not always positive definite, pick such $A$ and pick $B=0$.